# SQL Date Type Conversion Error

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I get the date like this

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

and try to insert to my database.

The error is :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

It was working yesterday. Today I delete all values in my table and is not working now

Comment: How do you try to insert data to your database? Show your code

Comment: If it's a date - please **treat it** as a date! Use `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date` and just go with that - **do not** needlessly convert dates to string and back!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app server and db server have different regional date setting. Also, DateTimePicker1.Value.Date yields a DateTime and you should use that to add it into the db without having to go through the regional conversion mess.

Answer (score 0):

Get your date using:

`CDate(DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString())`